# As3 - Get Movieclips That The Name Start With A Specific String

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a tile based game where `ta_*(number)*` and `ca_*(number)*` acts like bins. You drag things towards it and drop. But the level may put several these tiles.

I am not going to make something like:

```
if (my_mc.hitTestObject(ta_0) || my_mc.hitTestObject(ta_1) || my_mc.hitTestObject(ta_2).........)
```

Because some may not exist and throw an error at me, and I don't want to make like hundreds of them.

**Is there a way to find movieclips on stage that start with the name "ta_" and "ca_"?**

So that I can get: `ta_1`, `ta_2`.....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Unless you loop on `getChildAt()` and check all children's names.

But, why don't you add your *bins* to an array when creating them?
(I assume you create them dynamically)

```
var myBinArray:Array = new Array(10);

for (var i:int = 0; i < myBinArray.length; i++)
{
    var myBin = new Bin();
    myBinArray[i] = myBin;
}
```

Then you simply loop on your array:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < myBinArray.length; i++)
{
    if (mybinArray[i] != null)
        if (my_mc.hitTestObject(mybinArray[i])
        {
            // statements
            // and here I assume you want to break for loop
        }
}
```